# How can I get individual numbers from a 4 digit number?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a 4 digit number ex. 1234 how can I break that down into it's component numbers

```
int i = 1;
int o = 2;
int p = 3;
int a = 4;
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Just as an aside, you should rethink naming a int variable o. It can easily lead to confusion on anyone reading your code when you write `int ten = o * 5;` Even aside from looking kinda like a 0, it isn't descriptive at all which _likely_ makes it a poor name.

Comment: Jordan - Good point. Agreed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some basic math:

```
int num = 1234;
int i = num / 1000 % 10;
int o = num / 100 % 10;
int p = num / 10 % 10;
int a = num % 10;
```

Comment: Would anyone care to explain why this was down voted? This is exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: Maybe someone can explain why my comment was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

This function will extract the least-significant four digits to an array.

```
void extractFourDigits(int digits[4], int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        digits[3-i] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm... that sure doesn't look like Obj-C.

Comment: @Undo Why not? Objective-C is a superset of C. It is perfectly valid to have C functions in Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes... but it decreases the readability of your code. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: @Undo: Feel free to propose a "more readable" alternative.